# Find all string occurence in Larg Text using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have Large Text may contains 68915 words, I need to extract all matched string 
example:

```
u0022Feature\u0022,\u0022geometry\u0022:{\u0022type\u0022:\u0022Point\u0022,\u0022coordinates\u0022:[34.479741,31.529396]},\u0022properties\u0022:{\u0022name\u0022:\u0022\\u003Ca
```

How to extract ALL Coordinates [34.479741,31.529396] ?

Comment: You should add what you have done so far. Please remember that SO is not a code writing service. Here's a hint on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: How have you ended up with that string? It's very badly encoded JSON. If you fix the encoding you can just deserialise the string to an object and retrieve it's properties as normal

Comment: you can use this /\[.*?\]/ regular expression to extract all between [ ] but this is on assumption that you will have just one co-ordinate

Comment: This seems to be geojson reformatted... Please show the initial json